# Which MySQL variable sets the default collate of local variable?

Tags: mysql, collation

Say I have this stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE x(
)
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN

DECLARE test VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4';

-- ...

END
```

What is the mysql server variable that define the local variable `test`'s collation?

It currently is (thanks, mysql 8.0...) `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` so I get yield a "nice" `Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='` in a later on code.

Setting

```
DECLARE test VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci';
```

Removes the `Illegal collation` error, so I'm sure it's this variable that has the bad 0900 collation.

But, no, I'm not gonna rewrite all my local variables in all my procedures to set this explicit collation. So how do I set this globally for the server? or at least, how to I set this for the connection?

So far, I have the default mysql 8 configuration besides the following:

```
[mysqld]
skip-log-bin
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
character_set_server = utf8mb4
collation_server = utf8mb4_general_ci

# character_set_database  = utf8mb4
# collation_database = utf8mb4_general_ci
# character_set_client = utf8mb4
# character_set_connection = utf8mb4
# collation_connection = utf8mb4_general_ci
# character_set_results = utf8mb4
```

and this statement run at client connection:

```
SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4, NAMES utf8mb4, collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_general_ci', lc_messages = 'en_US', time_zone = '+00:00'
```

Commented out variables are those throwing a `unknown variable '...=...'` when trying to start mysql server, despite these variables being [listed in mysql 8 documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_collation_connection) tho...

Comment: Could you explain exactly when you get that message. Illegal mix of collations. I added your variable with uf8mb4 the default collation is utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci and a added a new variable without any further setting and compared them, no message under mysql workbench

Comment: Seems like there are two questions:  What is the implicit collation for a `DECLARE`? and What is the implicit collation for a constant?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that `test` is later on set to a value from a table column that is in `utf8mb4_general_ci` : `SET test = (SELECT type FROM oc WHERE id = idOc);` so that was where the collation mismatched because of the local variable one.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html):

> If CHARACTER SET and COLLATE are not present, **the database character set and collation in effect at routine creation time are used**. To avoid having the server use the database character set and collation, provide an explicit CHARACTER SET and a COLLATE attribute for character data parameters.

Most likely, the stored procedure was created before you updated the configuration, in which case all you need to do is drop and recreate them so that they use the new defaults.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE x` will provide the charset and collation.

Comment: Nope, it was dropped & recreated for every test. But I finally found [`default_collation_for_utf8mb4`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_collation_for_utf8mb4) which seems to set the `COLLATION` to use for `CHARSET 'utf8mb4'` local variables (and such) so I found my answer :)